# Call WCF Service from bat file

Tags: wcf, batch-file

is it possible to call a Methode of a WCF Service in a bat file. We want to test if the WCF Service works correct after the Server was restartet.

Answer (score 0):

There are no commands within the BAT file universe that will allow you to contact a WCF service directly, however you could use a BAT file to run an existing console program that can connect and interact with a WCF service. So the answer is both yes and no; not directly, but through a separate program yes.

If you need some simple, clickable way of accessing a WCF service, I'd go with a Powershell or VB script (assuming you're in a windows environment).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will be able to use `PowerShell`? It would be easier then. Create script with content:

```
$url = 'http://yoursite.url/example.svc'
$action = "`"http://some.namespace/method`""
$SOAPRequest = [xml]@'heregoesxmlmessage'@

write-host "Sending SOAP Request To Server: $url" 
$soapWebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url) 
$soapWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", $action)

$soapWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=`"utf-8`"" 
$soapWebRequest.Accept      = "text/xml" 
$soapWebRequest.Method      = "POST" 

write-host "Initiating Send." 
$requestStream = $soapWebRequest.GetRequestStream() 
$SOAPRequest.Save($requestStream) 
$requestStream.Close() 

write-host "Send Complete, Waiting For Response." 
$resp = $soapWebRequest.GetResponse() 
$responseStream = $resp.GetResponseStream() 
$soapReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]($responseStream) 
$ReturnXml = [Xml] $soapReader.ReadToEnd() 
$responseStream.Close() 

write-host "Response Received."
$ReturnXml.OuterXml | out-file ".\test.xml"
write-host $ReturnXml.OuterXml
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers Powershell is probably the best way to go using the `New-WebServiceProxy` cmdlet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849841.aspx

Example from the link above:

```
PS C:\> $URI = "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL"
PS C:\>$zip = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -Namespace WebServiceProxy -Class USZip
PS C:\> $zip.getinfobyzip(20500).table
CITY      : Washington
STATE     : DC
ZIP       : 20500
AREA_CODE : 202
TIME_ZONE : E
```